# Magento "The connection was reset" Error

Tags: php, magento, connection-reset

Hi I am facing issue in Magento it is showing error

**in Mozilla**

> The connection was reset

**in Chrome**

> www.mydomain.com page isn’t working
>   www.mydomain.com  didn’t send any data.
>   ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

[image]

I have noticed that while loading model we get this issue.

```
$model = Mage::getModel('qquoteadv/qqadvcustomer')->load(900)
```

Please help to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't listed all the things you've tried already, as such it could be a lot of things.

With anything like this, I'd firstly try flushing the APC cache by adding the following to your **index.php** file (located in the root of your Magento installation):

```
apc_clear_cache();
```

as well as:

```
apc_clear_cache('user');
```

Once you've tested the above (whether or not it works) make sure you comment out the above two lines...

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-clear-cache.php

Comment: David thanks but it did not worked for me . There was issue in custom model. It was extending other model which was creating problem i just removed that and extended the core abstract class as per magento and it worked for me.